# How to integrate javascript code with web application using Genexus

Tags: javascript, genexus

I'm new at using GeneXus, but I need to use it for a project and in that project I have to draw some diagrams. To draw the diagram I have developed a tool in javascript, and now I need to know how to integrate javascript code in a GeneXus web application. I have seen all the videos in the series "GeneXus course Version: X Evolution 2", but I can't find any information about it.

I also would like to know if it is possible to customise the html and the css.
If you can point me where I can find that kind of information it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to integrate your JavaScript code into GeneXus is by creating a [User Control](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?4940).

Another possibility is to add the JavaScript code inline in a TextBlock, but the User Control approach is more flexible and keeps your GeneXus code cleaner.

The CSS can be customized by modifying the [Theme](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?4447).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. When I saw the video about Controllers I didn't realize what could be done with them. Now I get it.

Anyway I followed the "Hello World" tutorial, but it doesn't work, I have read the full description but I don't know why it doesn't work. Maybe I will post the code and ask for help.

Comment: Your link of User control does not work. It's very high level description, can you please elaborate a little more?